# What is the correlation between the Android package manager class and the package manager tool accessible by ADB?

Tags: android, adb

From what I found online, the package manager (pm) class is documented at [Android package manager class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager) while the tool is at [Android package manager ADB tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb). Looking at the [PackageManager class source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java) it does not seem to be using the pm tool. As for pm tool source code, I could not find any.

A similar question with activity manager arises but I assume the answer to one would answer the other.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What about https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/742a67127366c376fdf188ff99ba30b27d3bf90c/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java ? It is from the package `com.android.commands.pm` and parses/processes the pm command-line

Comment: Hi yes upon inspection that does help my question. I found a solution and write an answer when I have the time. Basically, the class and the command both make us of the package manager service that is started at android start up.